# Como centralizar blocos html e mante-los mesmo após zoom na página

Tags: html5, css3

Não estou conseguindo centralizar meu bloco Pai (bloco vermelho) no centro. Quero  que ele permaneça no centro de forma que mesmo após o zoom na página ainda fique centralizado. Não estou conseguindo também, através do css, acessar as propriedades de "margin", "border" e "padding", nem alterar o fundo branco atrás do bloco Pai (vermelho). Sou inciante e estou estudando html e css. Peço compreensão. OBS: Zerando o css consegui alterar a propriedade "margin", mas não queria zera-lo.

HTML:

```
<div class="principal">
    <header class="header">
        Cabeçalho! Faça suas pesquisas aqui!
    </header>

    <article class="busca">
            <form  class="form" method="POST" action="classes/Controller.php">
                CEP: <input type="text" name="cep" placeholder="Insira o cep" required/>
                <input type="submit" /></p>
            </form>
    </article>

    <article class="data">
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
    </article>

    <footer class="rodape">
        Rodapé! Todos os direitos reservados.
    </footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.principal{
margin:0;
position:fixed;
background-color: red;
width:600px;
height:600px;
padding:1px;
border:0;
}
.header{
position:relative;
top:12%;
text-align:center;
font-size:150%;
font-family:Georgia;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.busca{
position:relative;
top:17%;
background-color:purple;
height:150px;
width:580px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
text-align:center;

}.form{
font-size:20px;
position:relative;
background-color:pink;
top:50px;
}
.data{
position:relative;
top:100px;
background-color:yellow;
height:150px;
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
.rodape{
position:relative;
top:110px;
text-align:center;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua div com `position: fixed` fica relativa ao `body`, e sem especificar posição com `top`, `right`, `left` ou `bottom` ela vai ficar na posição natural, que é no canto esquerdo superior do body.

> Não é preciso colocar `margin: 0` na div principal porque já é `0` por padrão.

Para centralizar essa div fixa, há diversas maneiras. Como a div possui largura fixa (`width:600px;`), você pode usar <s>a gambiarra</s> uma técnica de posicionar a div 50% à esquerda com `left: 50%` e depois voltar a sua metade negativa com `margin-left: -301px`. Por que `301px`? Por causa do `padding: 1px`. A largura da div é a soma do width + padding nas laterais (+ bordas, de houver). Como a sua div possui 600px da largura e 1px de padding, ela terá no total 602px de largura, e a metade disso é 301px. Isso só funciona com elementos que possuem largura fixa.

Veja (execute em tela cheia):

```css
.principal{
/*margin:0;*/
position:fixed;
background-color: red;
width:600px;
height:600px;
padding:1px;
border:0;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -301px;
}
.header{
position:relative;
top:12%;
text-align:center;
font-size:150%;
font-family:Georgia;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.busca{
position:relative;
top:17%;
background-color:purple;
height:150px;
width:580px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
text-align:center;

}.form{
font-size:20px;
position:relative;
background-color:pink;
top:50px;
}
.data{
position:relative;
top:100px;
background-color:yellow;
height:150px;
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
.rodape{
position:relative;
top:110px;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="principal">
    <header class="header">
        Cabeçalho! Faça suas pesquisas aqui!
    </header>

    <article class="busca">
            <form  class="form" method="POST" action="classes/Controller.php">
                CEP: <input type="text" name="cep" placeholder="Insira o cep" required/>
                <input type="submit" /></p>
            </form>
    </article>

    <article class="data">
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
        Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui! Endereço aqui!<br>
    </article>

    <footer class="rodape">
        Rodapé! Todos os direitos reservados.
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente e eu entendi a sua explicação! Mas eu ainda não consegui mudar a parte em branco do bg. A parte branca que fica atrás da div Pai

Comment: Pra isso vc coloca `body{ background-color: black; }`... irá ficar com fundo preto

Comment: Mto obrigado pelas informações. Se não for pedir mto, gostaria de tirar mais uma dúvida. Como faria pra deixar a div Pai (vermelho) ocupando todo o top e bottom, mesmo dando zoom, tbm?

Comment: Consegui alterando o height da div Pai para 100% Obrigado!

Comment: É isso mesmo ;)